Surface area element in 4-dimensions
In Dirac's "General Theory of Relativity" (p. 40) he says "If we take two small contravariant vectors $\xi^\mu$ and $\zeta^\mu$, the element of surface area that they subtend is determined by the antisymmetric two-index tensor $dS^{\mu\nu}=\xi^\mu\zeta^\nu-\xi^\nu\zeta^\mu$. Here he is working in four dimensions $\mu = (0,1,2,3)$.
How exactly does he get this? (And what exactly is meant by "determined"?) It looks very cross-product like, but there is no cross product in four dimensions. It makes sense, inasmuch as $dS$ shrinks as the two vectors become more parallel.
He gives the simple example where $\xi^\mu = (0,dx^1,0,0)$ and $\zeta^\mu = (0,0,dx^2,0)$. Then $dS^{12}=dx^1dx^2$ and $dS^{21}=-dx^1dx^2$.
Need some enlightenment here. Thanks in advance.

You need to learn about differential forms. You will get the surface area of a given (oriented) surface by integrating a $2$-form.
